# PHP Function is not showing up unless I declare function in function

Tags: php, function, class, joomla, declaration

I am creating a PHP script where I am attempting to reverse engineer a Joomla plugin for Community Builder.  To do this I need to build several custom functions within a single PHP class.  Here is a code snippet to help define the issue:

```
function gethelloworldTab() {
    $this->cbTabHandler();
}

function showMeThaMoney(){
    echo 'cashola';
}

function getDisplayTab($tab,$user,$ui) {
    global $_CB_framework;

    $baba = $this->showMeThaMoney();        

    $return = null;
    $params = $this->params; // get parameters (plugin and related tab)

    $is_helloworld_plug_enabled = $params->get('hwPlugEnabled', "1");
    $helloworld_tab_message = $params->get('hwTabMessage', "");

    if ($is_helloworld_plug_enabled != "0") {
        if($tab->description != null) {
            $return .= "\t\t<div class=\"helloworld_class\">"
                . $tab->description    // html content is allowed in descriptions
                . "</div>\n";
        }


        $return .= '\t\t<div>\n'
            . "<p>\n"
            . htmlspecialchars($helloworld_tab_message) . "\n" // make all other output html-safe
            . "</p>\n"                
            . $baba . "\n"
            . "</p>\n"
            . "</div>\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
}
```

As you can see, I would like to build out my custom classes outside of the `getDisplayTab` function.  I will then use all of the custom function variables to build the view in the `$result` output.

Is there a better way?  Did I make a simple error?

---

Update: I have changed the `$baba = showMeThaMoney();` to `$baba = $this->showMeThaMoney();` but the `cashola` is echoed to the top of the page.  Rather, I would like the `cashola` echo to be applied to the variable and displayed through the `return $return;` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to a function of a class (i.e. a method of the class), you can't just call the function directly. You have to call it through the class. This is commonly done with `$this`.

So you want to do something like this:

```
 $baba = $this->showMeThaMoney();
```

That should actually call the `showMeThaMoney` function as part of your plugin class.

Comment: dohhh... spoke too soon.  this will echo `cashola` at the top of the article, but it does not place it in the `$return` statement.

Comment: so change `echo 'cashola';` to `return 'cashola';`

Comment: Thanks David, that definitely fixed it.